# Mак рестартанул просто посреди работы

Tags: macos, железо, mac

Mак рестартанул просто посреди работы. Написал:

> "Your mac restarted because of a problem"

Чем вызвана проблема?

Вот логи:

```
Anonymous UUID:       EDD2C31B-F92C-9B18-E7C0-A297E966799C

Sat Jul 11 21:05:54 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800c3cfdab): Kernel trap at 0x0000000000000000, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x000000000f8a2000, CR4: 0x00000000000026e0
RAX: 0xffffff800c189020, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff801d6c6db0, RDX: 0x00000000000000ff
RSP: 0xffffff800c14a720, RBP: 0xffffff80edc20e40, RSI: 0x0000000000000008, RDI: 0xffffff801dfe5d80
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x7fffffffffffffff, R10: 0xffffff801ef98600, R11: 0x00000000e0000000
R12: 0x000000000000000e, R13: 0xffffff80dd35b900, R14: 0x000007ea0222fe0c, R15: 0xffffff800c14a720
RFL: 0x0000000000010083, RIP: 0x0000000000000000, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff800c14a3b0 : 0xffffff800c2dab52 
0xffffff800c14a430 : 0xffffff800c3cfdab 
0xffffff800c14a610 : 0xffffff800c3ebc03 
0xffffff800c14a630 : 0x0 
0xffffff80edc20e40 : 0xffffff7f8d8aa589 
0xffffff80edc20e90 : 0xffffff800c8b8b8e 
0xffffff80edc20ed0 : 0xffffff800c8d8503 
0xffffff80edc20f10 : 0xffffff7f8eb3ea91 
0xffffff80edc20f50 : 0xffffff7f8eb76f5a 
0xffffff80edc20f60 : 0xffffff7f8eb7f145 
0xffffff80edc20f80 : 0xffffff800c3ceffc 
0xffffff80edc20fd0 : 0xffffff800c3ebdc6 
0xffffff8018603f40 : 0xffffff800c2f22fd 
0xffffff8018603f90 : 0xffffff800c2f27f0 
0xffffff8018603fb0 : 0xffffff800c3ca3f7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(4.0)[A29C7512-D3A8-3AED-9721-3A5FF1A32EB2]@0xffffff7f8eb70000->0xffffff7f8ebcffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f8d7c1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5F5B9213-0BE4-33DA-9DC6-5859D824DC7D]@0xffffff7f8cb4d000
         com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC(1.7)[04696395-E633-3657-89BD-9908A5C60F56]@0xffffff7f8eb3d000->0xffffff7f8eb3ffff
         com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCI(1.0.1)[E90113BB-92F1-3D96-B2F5-F0B0CAAE6F4A]@0xffffff7f8d8a3000->0xffffff7f8d8c0fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI(1.0.1)[0D241802-E006-3A72-B3C5-09ABDE37DAE0]@0xffffff7f8d838000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.0.1)[79D250A3-843A-3750-BE64-A252CF17A148]@0xffffff7f8d5b9000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15G22010

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 21 20:07:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3248.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7564B0E7-EB5D-3887-BA79-59C870165AB1
Kernel slide:     0x000000000c000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800c200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800c100000
System model name: Macmini3,1 (Mac-F22C86C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 8702139836653
last loaded kext at 16390011909: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8d479000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 172239745110: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8d943000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f4
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.22
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   700.38.27
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.9
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDMouse   185.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse  185.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  303.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: Macmini3,1, BootROM MM31.0081.B06, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.35f0
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400, NVIDIA GeForce 9400, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x04EF, 0x5465616D2D456C6974652D31333333202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x04EF, 0x5465616D2D456C6974652D31333333202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x90), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.39.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f4, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Crucial_CT250MX200SSD1, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5670S
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Optical USB Mouse
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: HD Pro Webcam C920
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Cruzer Blade
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 2):

Оперативной памятью, не так давно задавал данный вопрос. [Ошибка](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT200553) оказалась такая же как и у вас.